# How to put a Legend under a figure?

Tags: fonts, floats, legend

In my document I got a figure with a lot of symbols in it like this:
[image: Example picture]
I want to add a legend to it, explaining all the symbols used. How do I achieve this?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{Grafiken/Momentanpol}
\caption{Fahrzeug in der schnellen Kurvenfahrt\cite{Pfeffer2011}}
%\\
%\begin{table}
%\begin{tabular}{ll}
%$F_{W,y}$: Reifenquerkräfte & $\alpha$: Schräglaufwinkel\\
%$\beta$: Schwimmwinkel & $\delta$: Radlenkwinkel 
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\label{Momentanpol}
\end{figure}
```

I tried putting the outcommented code right into the caption to achieve a legend with 2 columns, but it produced an awfull lot of errors. If you need those errors to help me (which I don't suspect) just let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as a `figure` environment is not required to use `\includegraphics`, a `table` environment is not required to use `tabular`. Remove the `table` environment and it works fine.

For the new image you added to your question, it would make sense to use a numbered list instead of a `tabular`, i.e.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Thing numbered 1
\item Gadget numbered 2
% Etc. 
\end{enumerate}
```

Here is a variation, with alignment at the colons.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}
\caption{Fahrzeug in der schnellen Kurvenfahrt\cite{Pfeffer2011}}

\begin{tabular}{r@{: }l r@{: }l}
$F_{W,y}$ & Reifenquerkräfte & $\alpha$ & Schräglaufwinkel\\
$\beta$& Schwimmwinkel & $\delta$& Radlenkwinkel 
\end{tabular}
\label{Momentanpol}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much! EDIT: btw it looks a lot better with the alignment you suggested.

Comment: There is also \item Thing \dotfill \makebox[0.25in][r]{1}